# What is required to use ipython in ironpython?

Tags: ironpython, ipython

I'd love to use IronPython to explore the .net runtime and libraries, but coming from CPython I miss [IPython](http://ipython.scipy.org/moin/)'s completion and shortcuts.

Last time I checked IPython couldn't be used due to a lack of sys.getframe, but the latest beta versions included support for it.

Is there anything lacking?

Can one start to use IPython with IronPython, and if so, what must one do?

Answer (score 2):

There were some issues in 2.6 Beta 1 which prevented it from work - see http://lists.ironpython.com/pipermail/users-ironpython.com/2009-June/010590.html.

That issue is fixed in the latest sources (and 2.6 Beta 2 is coming real soon now w/ the fix as well).  Someone just needs to give it a try and report back any additional issues or let us know if it works now.

Comment: Oh, great. I'll keep a lookout for it :) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This would be beyond useful.