# How to use IPython with IronPython

Tags: python, ironpython, ipython

What is the procedure to get IPython to use IronPython as it's Python interpreter?

I know there were previously some issues:  [What is required to use ipython in ironpython?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160501/what-is-required-to-use-ipython-in-ironpython)

But now that these issues should be fixed, how do i actually go about this?

The install doesn't detect IronPython as a version of the Python interpreter, not that I thought it would.  But I'm wondering how to do this.

I'd (ideally) like the ability to run both the CPython and IronPython versions of IPython on the same machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IPython script that installs on my system in `/usr/bin/ipython` is only two lines of code to invoke the interpreter:

```
from IPython import start_ipython
start_ipython()
```

So run that under IronPython and see how it works.

<s>But as of February 2011, it looks like there were still problems: http://groups.google.com/group/ironpy/browse_thread/thread/b90273c618e38763?pli=1</s>

**EDIT**: It works now, see [their instructions](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/wiki/Frequently-asked-questions#q-can-ipython-run-under-ironpython).

Comment: It should now be import IPython; Python.embed()

Comment: Just updated it to the latest code I see on my system ("start_ipython()").

Answer (score 2):

It now works as of IronPython 2.7.3 Alpha 1!

source: https://github.com/ipython/ipython/wiki/Frequently-asked-questions#wiki-q-can-ipython-run-under-ironpython